# How to stub a specific timezone for capybara testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I need to stub timezone to check how my JavaScript code will behave under a specific timezone. I cannot find a way to stub timezone to make sure it runs correctly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to test your application as if someone was using it in a different timezone, you should check out the [zonebie gem](https://github.com/alindeman/zonebie). It runs your application in a different timezone every time you run your tests, and you can also tell it to run your tests in a particular timezone.

[Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) might also be useful, it lets you freeze time, change the time to a different time in the middle of a test, or accelerate the passage of time.

If neither of those are what you're looking for, reading the code of those gems might help you figure out how to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a time zone as an environment variable when running your tests:

`TZ='UTC' rake:integration_tests`